# How to use same .arb file for multiple language codes with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, translation

Countries like Norway have a lot of different language codes. Is there a way to use the same translation/.arb file for multiple language codes or do I have to create 7 identical files? Which will be a pain to update later.

Examples of language codes for Norwegian:
*[no, no_NO, nb, nb_NO, nb_SJ, nn, nn_NO]*

Comment: You don't need to keep the duplicated files If you're not going to translate dialect languages and use the main language translations. According to the [supportedLocales property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp/supportedLocales.html) docs, Flutter should handle such fallbacks.